# SQL JOIN on two fields when one can be empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, join

I need a little advice on how to create an SQL statement for a particular case in my data.  I have two tables with the following fields:

```
horse_shows table

   horse_shows.showID
   horse_shows.horse_show_date
   horse_shows.horse_show_managerID
   horse_shows.horse_show_secretaryID - this field is allowed to be empty

show_managers table

   show_managers.managerID
   show_managers.name
   show_managers.email
```

Both horse_show_managerID and horse_show_secretaryID fields in the horse_shows table map to a managerID in the show_managers table.  Not all of the shows will have a show secretary, so the horse_show_secretaryID field in the horse_shows table can be blank.

I would like to print the show date, show manager, and show secretary for a show with a specific ID. And if the horse_show_secretaryID field in the horse_shows table is blank, I want it to just print blank for the secretary. So I tried this:

```
SELECT 
   horse_shows.horse_show_date, 
   show_managers.name, 
   show_secretaries.name 
FROM horse_shows 
   JOIN show_managers ON horse_shows.horse_show_managerID = show_managers.managerID 
   JOIN show_managers as show_secretaries ON horse_shows.horse_show_secretaryID = show_secretaries.managerID 
WHERE horse_shows.showID = 'XYZ';
```

But, the above statement only returns the row of the show with that showID if it finds a match on both the horse_show_managerID and the horse_show_secretaryID in the show_managers table. If the  horse_show_secretaryID field in the horse_shows table is blank (which is a valid condition), the statement returns no rows.  I would like it to return the date, manager and (a blank) secretary for the 'XYZ' show when the horse_show_secretaryID field is blank.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL?  Please learn to tag your questions appropriately.

Comment: I apologize for the seemingly incorrect tags. I am new at using sql and I did not realize that in this particular case which sql I was using made a difference. I thought I was asking a general sql question.  I am using mysql in this particular case I build wordpress websites as a hobby). But, I am also working with sql-server at work. So, I think both tags might apply here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `JOIN` on it's own will use an `INNER JOIN` meaning the join condition must be met. Use `LEFT JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT 
   horse_shows.horse_show_date, 
   show_managers.name, 
   show_secretaries.name 
FROM horse_shows 
   LEFT JOIN show_managers ON horse_shows.horse_show_managerID = show_managers.managerID 
   LEFT JOIN show_managers as show_secretaries ON horse_shows.horse_show_secretaryID = show_secretaries.managerID 
WHERE horse_shows.showID = 'XYZ';
```